# getting product that are in the cart from custom script

Tags: magento-1.9, php

So, I want to get all product in the shopping cart of current client and use it in third party "classical" php script.
Why code, mentioned below doesn't work as expected?

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::init();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
   $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
   $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
   echo $productName;
   echo $productPrice;
}
```

How do I access information of shop instance (Mage), which is running now?
Nor create new Mage object from the ground up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get front end session in your script just use

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
```

try below code (tested)

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
   $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
   $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
   echo $productName;
   echo $productPrice;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
It really works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a shell script that accesses the current cart items in the running Magento instance. I think you've recognized your own error: the code doesn't work as expected because you're creating your own `Mage` instance, as opposed to using the running instance in the Magento application. The pseudo-Magento environment that you've bootstrapped is a completely separate environment from the one that's actually running your store; thus, when you try to access objects in the running store, the environment can't find them.

This isn't an easy problem to get around, and I don't know of a way to run a shell script that accesses the running Magento process without creating a custom module. My suggestion would be to create a custom module that runs your code through an observer, or some other method. This will eliminate the issues that you have.

If you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: I understand you. I've written 

_Nor create new Mage object from the ground up._ 
Could you give me an example of basic module structure?
My script is not shell script, is a simple php  class for custom payment gateway. I want to get some information about products in the shopping cart and send POST request to bank gateway.

Comment: @Twissell your 1st four line shows it is custom script. As you said you want to get some information about products of the shopping cart in  custom payment gateway, then there will be some `redirectAction` in your custom payment controller. try to add your logic in that action

Comment: custom script is not **shell-script** for php-cli

Comment: @Twissell both are the same. If you are trying to retrieve quote in shell script it will not going to give you cart item due to different object instance

Comment: @GopalPatel

So, you are right. It is shell-script in terms of Magento. But shell-script is a bash script usually. Thus is offtopic question of terminology :-)